# Where to find Sparkfun's 1.0mm pitch connectors?

Tags: connector, sparkfun

I'm trying to buy [these recently stocked connectors from Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10206) from either Farnell or Digikey, but have no idea what they are called or how to find them. Also, what about the female connector that mates to this? And would I be easily (without an expensive tool) be able to crimp connectors for this series of connectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of connector is known as "wafer connectors" or "PCB SMT connector" or "Conn Header".

My suggestion for a search on google for a similar product: [conn header 2pos 1mm right angle](http://www.google.com.br/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=conn+header+2pos+1mm+right+angle)

Comment: http://au.element14.com/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/sm02b-srss-tb-lf-sn/header-r-a-2way/dp/1679117

do these look right?

Comment: Yes, they do. I think so.

Answer (score 3):

Are 1.0mm pitch terminals easy to crimp? No.

Having bought some 1mm crimp connectors in the past thinking "that's huge" (in soldering pitch terms), I soon regretted it after having crimped 30.  In later projects when I needed a bunch of low-current connections I used [FFCs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7589/looking-for-a-board-to-board-cable/7592#7592).

If you only have two crimps to make, it might be worth a shot, though if you can find pre-crimped pigtails, I would jump on that.